# About or around when referring to approximate age?

Tags: word-choice, grammar

I am not sure which one is the correct word for beginning this sentence. Is it just a stylistic choice?

I was **around** 10 years old when...

or

I was **about** 10 years old when...

Comment: I think there is a difference that may be more than stylisitic. I'm not sure why someone has voted to close. I'll try to come back to this tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a stylistic choice.

> **About** *adverb* 
>   
> 3. (Used with a number or quantity) approximately: "reduced by about 5 percent"

- [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/about)

> **Around** *adverb* 
>   
> 5. Approximately; about:

- [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/around)